# Running independent tasks sequentially using celery

Tags: python, celery, task

I have these two tasks and I want them to run in order:
remove_instagram_data first then run task_collect_instagram_posts task. But task_collect_instagram_posts runs first.

This is the code I'm executing :
(remove_instagram_data.si(payload) | (task_collect_instagram_posts.si(stream.id, is_daily_task=False)))()

The other issue is after one task completes it won't proceed to another task. It only executes one task.

Comment: I think this is happening because task A always has a pending state that's why it is not moving to the second task. I tried to resolve "Always Pending" issue by setting these variables: task_track_started=True, task_ignore_result=False but it is still showing the Pending state.

Comment: If it is always pending, are you sure you have workers to execute it?